# Layer dimension mismatch when going from a CNN layer to a Linear Layer

Tags: python, math, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am currently trying to dynamically generate a number of models that have different amounts of CNN layers to test accuracy against the Fashion Mnist dataset. My `create_cnn_model` works for  layer_count sizes from 1 to 9, but after 10 it fails. I am doing something wrong with calculating the last linear layer's size.

for context, my `create_cnn_model` function adds a MaxPool2D layer after every 3 convolutional layers. At the end of creating my `n` CNN layers I go ahead and add a Flatten and Linear layer.

Now there are two places I am unsure of. First off, is how I am using the "factor"  variable in the `create_cnn_model` function. I hope I am understanding it correctly and utilizing it as such. The other issue is the last linear layer. I'm honestly not sure If I am calculating that properly.

```py
#Whats the width and height of our images?
W, H = 28, 28 #
#How many values are in the input? We use this to help determine the size of subsequent layers
D = 28*28 #28 * 28 images 
#Hidden layer size
n = 256 
#How many channels are in the input?
C = 1
#how many filters per convolutional layer
n_filters = 32
#How many classes are there?
classes = 10

leak_rate = 0.01

loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# function altered to support optional batch_norm
def cnnLayer(in_filters, out_filters=None, kernel_size=3, batch_norm=False):
    """
    in_filters: how many channels are coming into the layer
    out_filters: how many channels this layer should learn / output, or `None` if we want to have the same number of channels as the input.
    kernel_size: how large the kernel should be
    batch_norm: defines if a batch norm layer should be included
    """
    if out_filters is None:
        out_filters = in_filters #This is a common pattern, so lets automate it as a default if not asked
    padding=kernel_size//2 #padding to stay the same size
    layers = []
    layers.append(nn.Conv2d(in_filters, out_filters, kernel_size, padding=padding))
    if batch_norm:
        layers.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(out_filters))
    layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(leak_rate))
    return nn.Sequential( # Combine the layer and activation into a single unit
        *layers
    )


def create_cnn_model(layer_count: int, include_bn_layer: bool):
    layers = []
    factor = 1;
    for layer_index in range(layer_count):
        if layer_index == 0:
            layers.append(cnnLayer(C, n_filters))
        elif layer_index % 3 == 0 and layer_index != 0:
            layers.append(nn.MaxPool2d((2,2)))
            layers.append(cnnLayer(factor*n_filters, 2*factor*n_filters))
            factor = factor * 2
        else:
            layers.append(cnnLayer(factor*n_filters))
    layers.append(nn.Flatten())
    layers.append(nn.Linear((D*n_filters)//(factor), classes))
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

Here's what the model looks like when I've run

```py
create_cnn_model(10, False)
```

Model string rep:

```
Sequential(
  (0): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (2): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (3): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (4): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (5): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (6): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (7): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (8): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (9): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (10): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (11): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2), padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (12): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  )
  (13): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  (14): Linear(in_features=3136, out_features=10, bias=True)
)
```

Error Line

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x2304 and 3136x10)
```

If I'm missing any information please let me know, I've probably spent close to 4 hours on this.

Answer (score 3):

it's hard to tell but pass a dummy tensor through the layers until the second last layer and then check the shape of the output tensor:

```
def create_cnn_model(layer_count: int, include_bn_layer: bool):
    layers = []
    factor = 1;
    dummy = torch.zeros((1, C, W, H))
    for layer_index in range(layer_count):
        if layer_index == 0:
            layers.append(cnnLayer(C, n_filters))
        elif layer_index % 3 == 0 and layer_index != 0:
            layers.append(nn.MaxPool2d((2,2)))
            layers.append(cnnLayer(factor*n_filters, 2*factor*n_filters))
            factor = factor * 2
        else:
            layers.append(cnnLayer(factor*n_filters))
        dummy = nn.Sequential(*layers[:-2])(dummy)
        out_shape = dummy.shape[1:]  # exclude batch dimension
    layers.append(nn.Flatten())
    linear_in_features = out_shape[0] * out_shape[1] * out_shape[2]
    layers.append(nn.Linear(linear_in_features, classes))
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the comment. I was stuck on this for so long.

Your idea works perfectly, but I just iterated over the entire layer set right before the last linear layer was added, grabbed the output dim size, and used that.